# How do you use sapply() with a "list" that includes two columns of data?

Tags: r

I am currently using `sapply` to call a weighted mean function that takes two inputs, a date and a date frame of multiple values per date,

```
sapply(unique(sort(d$Date, decreasing=TRUE)), WeightedMean, data=d))

WeightedMean <- function(date, data) {...}
```

but I would like to update this function to take three inputs.  I have created the code below, but am unable to reference both inputs in my `WeightedMean` function,

```
sapply(unique(d[order(d$Date, d$Id, decreasing=TRUE), c("Date", "Id")]), 
    WeightedMean, data=d)

WeightedMean <- function(date, id, data) {...}
```

Note that the `WeightedMean` function will filter the data by date and id and then calculate a summary value.  Is there a way I can update the above code to pass two parameters to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using an anonymous function.

You don't provide a working example, so the following code is untested but should work:

```
sapply(unique(d[order(d$Date, d$Id, decreasing=TRUE), c("Date", "Id")]), 
    function(x){WeightedMean(x$Date, x$Id, data=x)})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mapply` instead if `sapply`.  (The `m` means "multiple arguments".)

```
ordered_data <- unique(d[order(d$Date, d$Id, decreasing = TRUE), c("Date", "Id")])
with(ordered_data, mapply(WeightedMean, Date, Id))
```

Comment: This is probably a better approach than using `sapply`.  Do you know if there is a significant performance difference between 'sapply' and 'mapply'?